# PHP HyperLink not Executing Action

Tags: php

I have a php MVC hyperlink that redirects to the index.php page when clicked instead of going to the viewpath specified. No errors, notices or warnings.

Below is the menu list

```
 <ul>                   
        <li id="HTMLID" class="first fourColumns"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='index.php?action=get_subjects&class=<?php echo $classes[0]['class_id']; ?>'>My Subjects</a></li>
        <?php if ($myclass > 0):?>
        <li><a href='index.php?action=get_classes&teacher=<?php echo $_SESSION['userinfo']['id']; ?>'>My Class</a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <li><a href="report.php">Report</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Below is the controller class

```
 <?php
 class indexController extends Controller11
 {
function __construct()
{
    if(isset($_GET['class']))
        $this->class = $_GET['class'];

    //parent::Controller11();
}

function index()
{   
    include(VIEWPATH."home.php");
}

function get_subjects()
{
    $school_obj = new school();
    $sch_info = $school_obj->select_all(array('picture'));

    $this->class = $_GET['class'];
    $teacher_obj = new teacher();
    $subjects = $teacher_obj->get_subjects($_SESSION['userinfo']['id'],$this->class);
    $subjects_notes = $teacher_obj->get_notes($_SESSION['userinfo']['id'],$this->class);

    $_SESSION['work']['teacher'] = $_SESSION['userinfo']['id']; 
    include(VIEWPATH."your_subjects.php");
}

function get_classes()
{
    $school_obj = new school();
    $sch_info = $school_obj->select_all(array('picture'));

    $this->class = $_GET['class'];
    $teacher_obj = new teacher();
    $classes = $teacher_obj->get_classes($_SESSION['userinfo']['id']);

    $class_obj = new schoolClass();
    $student_count = $teacher_obj->get_student_count($this->class,$session,$term);

    $_SESSION['work']['teacher'] = $_SESSION['userinfo']['id']; 
    include(VIEWPATH."your_class.php");
}
 }
```

I have updated my local xammp to version 7.2, and it still works, but does nothing on web server which is also 7.2. Anyone knows why? Or can spot what am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have JS that hijacks a click event?

Comment: Thanx for your reply @Justinas. However i do not have any javascript in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it out. For some reason when i removed the __construct function it started working again.

I must look into __construct function and its uses.